# Coreplot graph fill color along y-axis

Tags: iphone, ios, graph, core-plot

![enter image description here][1]

Can anybody tell how to draw dark blue masked area on coreplot graph from y-axis 4 to 10 and through out the x-axis like i showed in the figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Core Plot calls that a "background limit band". There are examples in several of the example apps, including the Plot Gallery.

```
CPTPlotRange *range = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(4.0)
                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(6.0)];
CPTFill *bandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
[yAxis addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:range
                                                          fill:bandFill]];
```

Comment: I just want the background color will be filled only in positive quadrant .But I am facing some challenge in it. See link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/186007808/LimitBandColorIssue.png 

See my code below: CPTPlotRange *range = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(100.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(100.0)]; CPTFill *bandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]]; [y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:range fill:bandFill]]; Kindly correct me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri You can use the `gridLinesRange` to control the width of the limit band.

Comment: :Thank you so much #Sir. It really works for me. I have applied it previously as well but range value was not same as in visible axis range it is. that is why I was not getting correct result and main thing is that I was not confirmed that it will be fixed through grid lines otherwise i surely look it in a different way. After your answer I have just corrected my range values and got desired result. Thank you so much to you.

y.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(350)];