# Is it possible to fill a certain part of Graph in a color different from the rest using core plot?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I have created a scatter plot and filled its area with some color. Now I want only a particular portion of the Area Graph to be filled by a different color. 
How can I achieve it using core plot?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this question. [Coreplot graph fill color along y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042447/coreplot-graph-fill-color-along-y-axis). This should lead you to the right direction. The following is the answer by Eric in that post.

```
CPTPlotRange *range = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(4.0)
                                               length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(6.0)];
CPTFill *bandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
[yAxis addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:range
                                                          fill:bandFill]];
```