# Core plot fill graph along X axis?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I saw this question here: [Coreplot graph fill color along y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042447/coreplot-graph-fill-color-along-y-axis)

It answers how to fill the plot along the xaxis:

```
CPTPlotRange *range = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(4.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(6.0)];
CPTFill *bandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.2f]];
[xAxis addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:range
                                                          fill:bandFill]];
```

However, that gives me a graph like this:

[image]

I'd like the white color to only be under the graph line, not above it.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you want the fill under the whole plot or just a segment like the limit band?

Comment: I'd like an under-the-plot limit band.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break the plot into pieces and use different plots for each segment. Apply an `areaFill` to the segment you want highlighted.

You can also add an enhancement request on the Core Plot [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues) to have this added natively to the scatter plot.